# YouCompleteMe missing Latex option after inserting :let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'

Tags: git, bash, vim, terminal, vundle

YouCompleteMe(YCM) is able to auto-complete python and vim code on my setup. I am currently unable to get latex auto-completition to work on vim. I tried inserting the following command in begin-end vundle script within the vimrc file

```
let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'
```

however YCM is unable to auto-complete latex code within .tex files. I installed vim-latex-suit, with no success. Is it possible their a default option to be enabled in the vimrc file that is also required to enable latex autocomplete, or am I missing something else. Keep in mind, I deleted the default vimrc file by mistake.

Comment: Everything should be done in `~/.vim`, *never* `/etc/vim/`.

Comment: By following the instructions in Vundle's `README`. The command is even in your question.